# Centered div larger than its container overflow scroll

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, transform, centering

Having an absolutely placed and perfectly centered ("translate trick") div within a container: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Youptube/1wf7fh8o/7/).

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='content'>
    <p>
      centered...
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

#container{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#content{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Now when this inner div becomes larger than it's container and the container has overflow: auto (scroll). It becomes impossible to get the utmost top and left part of the inner div to become visible within the container by scrolling it to the left and top and its maximum: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Youptube/vevot06w/2/).

```
#container{
  ...
  overflow: auto;
}

#content{
  ...
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  ...
}
```

The "same" thing happens when the inner div is scaled to a proportion that it overflows the container div: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Youptube/jcu2xeo8/4/).

```
#container{
  ...
  overflow: auto;
}

#content{
  ...
  transform: ... scale(5);
}
```

Any ideas on how to have the inner div stay centered and still be able to reach all its area by using the scrollbars of the container div? Or should the "centeredness" be dropped when the size overflows the container (possibly using javascript)? A pure css solution is much preferred.

Comment: I think this is related to the borders not being taken into account at some point.

Comment: No, borders are really far off if you enlarge the inner div's dimension and use the browsers inspector to see where the complete div is located...

Answer (score 0):

You could use some absolute positioning to do the centering, a max-height and max-width, and put the scroll on the inside container, like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/hnzo2sa4/

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 10px;
}

.bigger {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.same {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.smaller {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background: rgba(987, 654, 321, .6);
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container bigger">
  <div class='content'>
    <p>centered...</p>
    <p>centered...</p>
    <p>centered...</p>
    <p>centered...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container same">
  <div class='content'>
    <p>centered...</p>
    <p>centered...</p>
    <p>centered...</p>
    <p>centered...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container smaller">
  <div class='content'>
    <p>centered...</p>
    <p>centered...</p>
    <p>centered...</p>
    <p>centered...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Despite your effort this is not what I tried to explain and achieve. I am working further on it myself right now and think the top and left css properties should be changed alongside changes in the scale factor.